# Why disentangling the features of variation in representation?

Tags: datasets, papers, features, representation-learning

Consider the following excerpt from `abstract` of the research paper titled Better [Mixing via Deep Representations](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v28/bengio13.pdf) by Yoshua Bengio et al.

> It has been hypothesized, and supported with experimental evidence,
> that deeper representations, when well trained, tend to do a **better
> job at disentangling the underlying factors of variation**.

In general, as per my current knowledge, we want to preserve the factors that contribute to variation in the final representation. But, the abstract is contrary to that. Where am I going wrong? Why there is a need to disentangle the factors of variation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very similar question to the one asked you before, at least in terms of the answer. Again going with PCA as a simple example of building features, when you end up with the principal components those are linearly independent. One reason that linearly independent features are useful is interpretability (which you'd get to some extent with sparse PCA). Another reason is that if the features are linearly independent than learning from those features becomes simpler. This is what they mean by disentangling the factors of variation. The original factors (features) can be combined in several layers of hierarchy to build more complex features where each higher level feature independently accounts for some variation in the data.

**Update based on comment**

The term *factors of variation* means "things that contribute to the variation in the data". When you build a model with simple linear regression, then the only factors of variation are your initial features. When you build simple feedforward neural networks with a hidden layer, each unit in the hidden layer account for some percentage of the total variation in the data. The goal is to produce hidden units which independently account for some variation in the data. This is what the authors mean by *disentangling the underlying factors of variation*.

Comment: I am confused. Features of variance is the things to be preserved right?

Comment: Okay, so **disentangle the factors of variation** means **preserving the factors of variation with as much as possible disentanglement between them**. Am I correct?

Comment: More or less, it means preserving the variation in the data with independent component accounting for parts of the variation, but I think you understand what it means now.